# SQL Server 2005 XML Capabilities and backward compatibility

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I use `SQL Server 2005` with compatibility level `80`. If I don't set compatibility level then some modules of `ASP.NET` Web Application don't work because application was originally written with `SQL Server 2000`.

Now If I write a stored procedure that uses xml variable with functions node and values which I believe is `SQL Server 2005` specific feature and does not exist in `SQL Server 2000` would this be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML data type will work just fine even with compatibility level 80.

There are some differences in behaviour when you use `for xml` to construct XML.

[ALTER DATABASE Compatibility Level (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks. if I use any other T-SQL 2005 feature that sql server 2000 does not support then would it be a problem

Comment: @waqas Everything that is affected by compatibility level is listed in the link.